# id is not passing to the post action method for the second time in asp.net mvc 2.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have implemented a HttpPost action method called UserRegistration.for the first time if i entered all the user details into the form and click create button,if the username is already existed it shows the error like "UserName is already exist.please give different username" and remains in the same page.
(If the data is correct then it executed successfully.)

Now if i change the userName and directly click the create button,then it will show the error like eventid is not null for the UserRegistration post action method.for that again i have to go back to the previous page and once again i have to open the page or i have to refresh the page.

I am passing EventId to the post action.But i dont know why it is passing eventid for the first time but not for second time(in case of error occurs).

Comment: is the "eventid" part of the model? can you post code as well?

Comment: Please post some code and we try to give the solution.

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Comment: [HttpPost]
public ActionResult UserRegistration(string FirstName, string LastName, string LoginId, string Password, string ConfirmPassword,int eventid)
       {              
          string firstName = FirstName;
          string lastName = LastName;
          string userName = LoginId;
          string password = Password;
          string confirmPassword = ConfirmPassword;
          if (ModelState.IsValid)
          {
           MembershipUser name = Membership.GetUser(userName);
           if(name==null)
           {
  MembershipUser user = Membership.CreateUser(userName, password);

Comment: Roles.AddUserToRole(userName, "User");
UserProfile.NewUser.Initialize(userName, true);
UserProfile.NewUser.FirstName = firstName;
UserProfile.NewUser.LastName = lastName;
UserProfile.NewUser.Save();return       RedirectToAction("CreateAccountConfirmation", new { id = eventid });
 }
 else
 {
 MembershipCreateStatus status = MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName;
 ModelState.AddModelError("", AccountValidation.ErrorCodeToString(status));                  
 }ViewData["PasswordLength"] = MembershipService.MinPasswordLength; return View();